Unhandled Promise rejection: The Sharedruntime ID is missing. ; in Angular and OfficeAddins
I have created an angular project and added officeaddin for excel manifest.xml file .Now issue is i am trying to enable or disable the buttons in ribbon from the taskpane (home.component) but when i try that it shows the following error
excel-win32-16.01.js:25  Unhandled Promise rejection: The Sharedruntime ID is missing. ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: RichApi.Error: The Sharedruntime ID is missing.
Here is my manifest.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>b19ca25c-51cf-41e5-9e22-fb8482b052e8</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="excel-addin"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="A template to get started."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:4200/assets/icon-32.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:4200/assets/icon-64.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://localhost:4200</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Workbook"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
        <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
            <Set Name="SharedRuntime" MinVersion="1.1"/>
        </Sets>
    </Requirements>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:4200/index.html"/>
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
    <Runtimes>
                    <Runtime resid="ContosoAddin.Url" lifetime="long" />
                </Runtimes>
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <GetStarted>
            <Title resid="GetStarted.Title"/>
            <Description resid="GetStarted.Description"/>
            <LearnMoreUrl resid="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
          </GetStarted>
           <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <CustomTab id="ctPSForExcel">
              <Group id="CommandsGroup">
                <Label resid="CommandsGroup.Label"/>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                </Icon>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="TaskpaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="TaskpaneButton1">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton1.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton1.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton1.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                      <FunctionName>writeValue</FunctionName>
                                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
              <Label resid="TabGroup.Label" />
            </CustomTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:4200/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:4200/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:4200/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812"/>
         <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:4200/assets/commands/commands.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:4200/#/index.html"/>
            <bt:Url id="ContosoAddin.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:4200/#/index.html"/>
            <bt:Url id="Functions.Metadata.Url" DefaultValue="https://officedev.github.io/Office-Add-in-samples/Samples/excel-shared-runtime-scenario/src/functions/functions.json"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
       <bt:String id="TabGroup.Label" DefaultValue="PlasmaStudio for Microsoft Office" />
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Get started with your sample add-in!"/>
        <bt:String id="CommandsGroup.Label" DefaultValue="Commands Group"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
         <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton1.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="Your sample add-in loaded succesfully. Go to the HOME tab and click the 'Show Taskpane' button to get started."/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane"/>
         <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton1.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane"/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>

Here is my index.html file
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Excel</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="assets/functions/functions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/commands/commands.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/css/fabric.min.css" />

</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>


Here is my home.component file
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as commands  from "src/assets/functions/functions.js";
declare global {
  interface Window {
    state?: {
      // Define the properties of your state object here
      isStartOnDocOpen?: boolean;
      isSignedIn?: boolean;
      // ... other properties
    };
  }
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.postMessageToHost({ type: 'changeRibbonState', state: 'show' });
  }
  private postMessageToHost(message: any) {
    window.parent.postMessage(message, '*'); // Assuming host add-in is in the same parent frame
  }
 
}


Here is my command.js file
/*
 * Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license.
 * See LICENSE in the project root for license information.
 */

/* global global, Office, self, window */

Office.onReady(() => {
  
  window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    if (event.data && event.data.type === 'changeRibbonState') {
      console.log("hi")
        writeValues();
    }
  });

});

function writeValues(event){
  Office.ribbon.requestUpdate({
      tabs: [
        {
            id: "ctPSForExcel", 
            groups: [
                {
                  id: "CommandsGroup",
                  controls: [
                    {
                        id: "TaskpaneButton", 
                        enabled: false
                    }
                  ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    })
  
  event.completed();
}


function getGlobal() {
  return typeof self !== "undefined"
    ? self
    : typeof window !== "undefined"
    ? window
    : typeof global !== "undefined"
    ? global
    : undefined;
}

const g = getGlobal();

Office.actions.associate("writeValue",writeValues);


what is wrong here. when i directly cick on ribbon button i am able to disable or enable other buttons.. but from takspane i am not able to do it
I want to enable or disable the ribbon buttons from taskpane of Excelsheet

Someone else using angular reported the same issue: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/4368
